# Pandas to search the string based on the conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Question is a bit complicated, requesting to look into the snapshot for a better view/understanding
I have a data frame of 2 columns "Col-A", "Col-B"[https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw1hx.jpg][1].
I also have a CSV file data which has multiple columns.[https://i.stack.imgur.com/v72mM.jpg][1]

"Col-B" data of my dataframe will match the CSV file headers, 
for example, "Col-B" first-row item is "Password", hence I will have the column with the name "Password" in the CSV file.[https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTCZa.jpg][1]

Now what my code should perform is, if my dataframe "Col-B" is Password, then the password column of my CSV-file should be searched in the Col-A & first found string is my output. below is the code i tried.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/606736.CTS/Desktop/Keyword.xlsx", 
sheet_name='Sheet2')
CSV_file = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/606736.CTS/Desktop/Keyword.xlsx",
sheet_name='Sub-Cat') 

data['Col-C']= np.nan # for adding a new column

# Below code works perfectly fine for searching any one of the column 
# in the CSV-file, in the below code I am searching on "Password" Col, 
# but I want the code to take the column dynamically based on the 'Col-B' 
# of my dataframe.
# if col-B of my dataframe is "CPU", then 'CPU' column of the CSV-file 
# should be searched.
for i in data['Col-B']:
    for Key1 in CSV_file[i]:
        data.loc[(data['Col-A'].apply(lambda x: Key1 in x.split(' ')) & 
        (data['Col-C'].isna()), 'Col-C')] = Key1
data.head(3)
```

Comment: Does all Col-B is a column in CSV_file?

Comment: Yes, all col-B data will match the CSV_file hearders

Comment: You just need to for loop entire ```data``` dataframe, and use 'Col-B' as the column name for CSV_file, plus the code you have now that would work

Comment: for i in data['Col-B']:
    for Key1 in CSV_file[i]:
        data.loc[(data['Col-A'].apply(lambda x: Key1 in x.split(' ')) & (data['Col-C'].isna()), 'Col-C')] = Key1
data.head(3)

Comment: how do I add a clause saying if that particular column not found, search it from the column call 'others', which is in CSV_file

Comment: use ```try...except...``` clause

Comment: for i in data['Col-B']:
    for Key1 in CSV_file[i]:
        data.loc[(data['Col-A'].apply(lambda x: Key1 in x.split(' ')) & (data['Col-C'].isna()), 'Col-C')] = Key1 (this is not not working, search is not happening in the right columns.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me

```
for i in data['Col-B']:
    for Key1 in CSV_file[i]:
       data.loc[(data['Col-A'].apply(lambda x: Key1 in x.split(' ')) & 
       (data['Col-B']==i), 'Col-C')] = Key1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will take long time to run, if you have large dataframe

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    i = row['Col-B']
    for Key1 in CSV_file[i].to_list():
        if Key1 in row['Col-A']:
            data.loc[index,'Col-C'] = Key1
            Break
```